# dispatch async code error - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective C but have been working on Swift for a while now. I assumed Objective c to be logically similar to swift. I have to present an alert controller while I am processing a json data request; so I had to use dispatch async to get it to work in swift. Here's the code I used in Swift:

```
    func alertMessage(message : String) -> Void {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

But  I tried to do the same thing in objective C like so

```
- (void)alertMessage : (NSString*) message {
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:NULL];
[alert addAction:okAction];
[dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:NULL];
})];
}
```

I'm getting an error "expected identifier". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil]; may be this is causing the issue replace NULL with nil

Comment: In which line you are getting the error?

Comment: @Arun at the second last line })]; with the marker at ]

Comment: You don't need `[]` brackets around `dispatch_async` in the objective-c code.

Comment: @IrfanGul No. I had already tried that.

Comment: @ozgur You are right! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks mate!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its just syntax error. Try following

```
- (void)alertMessage : (NSString*) message {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:NULL];
    [alert addAction:okAction];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:NULL];
    });

}
```

Comment: The reason being that: `dispatch_async()` is a **C function**. Square brackets `[ ]` enclose **Objective-c methods**.

Answer (score 4):

Because “dispatch_async” is a C function, you should call it like this.

```
- (void)alertMessage : (NSString*) message {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:NULL];
    [alert addAction:okAction];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can try now

```
- (void)alertMessage : (NSString*) message {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:NULL];
    [alert addAction:okAction];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
         [self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Output:

[image]

Happy coding..